# Azure Synapse Pipeline - ForEach in ForEach not working

Tags: pipeline, azure-synapse

In Synapse I have a pipeline for orchestrating my work.

The first I do is to lookup the distinct priorities I have on my jobs. Then I create a ForEach for each of my priorities.

In that ForEach loop, I create another lookup which looks for my tasks with that specific priority and with another ForEach loop I will execute each task.

If I do this directly in the same pipeline, I get an error:

```
Error
{
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": null,
    "target": "pipeline//runid/ab56b3c8-244f-4e8a-b5cd-2cfff775e16c",
    "details": null,
    "error": null
}
```

But if I copy my inner Lookup task and ForEach loop to another pipeline and add the priority as a parameter, it works like a charm!

So: Is it possible to have a ForEach loop within a ForEach loop in Synapse or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nested logic operations in pipelines (both ADF and Synapse) are very limited. For example, you cannot place a *ForEach* or *Until* inside a *ForEach*, nor can you place any logic operation inside an *If* or *Switch*.

The way to work around this is by calling another pipeline (*Execute Pipeline*) and passing any relevant parameters. That pipeline would then be designed to perform operations over a single iteration. This creates a parent-child pipeline relationship. Depending on your scenario, you may need to run these sequentially by specifying "Wait on completion".